# Facebook Deauthorize CallBack Url not being pinged

Tags: facebook

I'm running a facebook app on localhost using wamp. My application is working fine on localhost. 
I've specified the deauthorize callback url in the app settings as

"http://localhost/MyApp/deauthorize.php"

But when I remove the app, deauthorize.php is not being pinged. I'm able to access this script over my machine. 
I tried http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug tool, but i gets error in parsing localhost URLs.
Is it that I can't give localhost url to deauthorize? or if I m missing something. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Of course* you can’t use a localhost address a callback URL, since from “out there” on the web there is no way of knowing that localhost is supposed to be *your* machine.

> I'm able to access this script over my machine.

But Facebook’s servers aren’t running on your machine …

If you want to get that to work for testing, get a DynDNS address somewhere, and make sure your web server is also accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thank You CBroe. I was just in a little doubt, that the call might be coming from the profile of the user (logged on my machine), thereby is able to access localhost. Thank You for answering.

Comment: If that was the case, it would hardly work for users who are _not_ logged in from your machine, would it? And that’s most of them, I assume ;-)

Comment: Yes indeed. The app is in the development phase, so i was just wanted to make sure that things are working fine, before putting it live. :)